# Proving a statement about continuous functions and integration / limits?

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a continuous function on $[0,+\infty)$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = c$.  Show that $$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} f(s)ds = c$$

How would you go about showing this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Choose $N$ (big), and split the integral into two integrals, one over $[0,N]$ and the other over $[N,x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply De l'Hopital's theorem, it's immediate!

Comment: How would you prove this using integrals and limits though?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$; since $f(x) \to c$ as $x \to \infty$, there exists an $N_0 > 0$ so that $|f(x) - c| < \epsilon$ for all $x > N_0$.  Since $f$ is continuous, find a $B > 0$ so that $|f(x) \le B$ for all $0 \le x \le N_0$.  Pick $N > N_0$ such that $\frac{N_0(B + |c|)}{N} < \epsilon$.

Now, if $x > N$, we  may write

$\displaystyle |\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(s) ds - c| = | \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(s) - c ds|$

$= \displaystyle | \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{N_0} f(s) - c ds + \frac{1}{x}\int_{N_0}^x f(s) - c ds| $

$\displaystyle \le \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{N_0} |f(s)| + |c| ds + \frac{1}{x} \int_{N_0}^x |f(s) - c| ds$.

The first integral can be estimated by $N_0\frac{B + |c|}{x} \le N_0 \frac{B + |c|}{N} < \epsilon $.  For the second integral, we have that $N_0 \le s$ so that our choice of $N_0$ implies that $|f(s) - c| < \epsilon$.  Thus the entire second integral is bounded by $\frac{(x - N_0) \epsilon}{x} < \epsilon$.